# Square Root program using Difference Equations

Tags: matlab, square-root, difference-equations

I made a program using difference equation initial conditions for each number, but as you can see the code didn't give me satisfying results, plus it took more loops than it's supposed to, it should be two runs for each number maximum. The square root of 5 = 2.23 after 2 loops.

```
N=4;
S=[5 10 15 27 40]; %root squared numbers input variables 
y1=[2 3 4 5 6]; %1st Initial conditions
for  i=0:1:1
for  n=1:1:3
y1(n)=0.5*(y1(i+1)+(S(n)./y1(i+1)))
end
end
```

Results  on command window:

```
y1 =
    2.2500    3.0000    4.0000    5.0000    6.0000
y1 =
    2.2500    3.3472    4.0000    5.0000    6.0000
y1 =
    2.2500    3.3472    4.4583    5.0000    6.0000
y1 =
    2.4205    3.3472    4.4583    5.0000    6.0000
y1 =
    2.4205    3.1674    4.4583    5.0000    6.0000
y1 =
    2.4205    3.1674    3.9516    5.0000    6.0000
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. It's unclear what you _expect_  as outputs, what would be a "satisfying" / expected result? Why do you assert that? Have you tried stepping through your code to find the specific point where the output diverges from your expectations? Keep in mind that we have zero contextual information other than what you include in the question for what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner loop does not address all elements of `y1`. Try this instead:

```
format long

S=[5 10 15 27 40]; 
y=[2 3 4 5 6]; 

% y=2*x*x'

for n=1:5
    for i=1:numel(S)
        y(i)=0.5*(y(i)+(S(i)./y(i)));
    end
    disp(y)
end
```

The closing line is

```
y =

   2.236067977499790   3.162277660168379   3.872983346207417

   5.196152422706632   6.324555320336758
```

The exact solution being

```
 S.^.5
 =
   2.236067977499790   3.162277660168380   3.872983346207417

   5.196152422706632   6.324555320336759
```

Now your 2 loops reach the expected values much faster.

Comment: Comment: The code in the question uses n that cannot go above amount elements in initial condition vector. Now n is the amount of loops so when using same approach for different approximation n can be increased to whatever satisfies error thresholds.